# Calculating the average of an array of logarithmic values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm calculating the average of an array of log values (decibels, if it matters) in JavaScript. It occurred to me that if the numbers are log values (where 55 is 10 times 54), the average decibel level isn't going to be the average of the logarithms. What's the best way to approach this?

Below is some code with how I would *normally* calculate an average value in JS. What would a graceful way to calculate the average of an array of log values in JavaScript?

```js
// These values are in decibels
const samples = [40, 50, 55, 80, 45];
document.getElementById('samples').innerText = JSON.stringify(samples);

let total = 0;

samples.forEach(value => {
  total = total + value;
});

const average = total / samples.length;

document.getElementById('avg').innerText = JSON.stringify(average);
```

```html
<div>
  Decibel samples:
  <span id="samples"></span>
</div>

<div>
  Average:
  <span id="avg"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `reduce()` `samples.reduce((ac,a) => ac + a,0)/samples.length`

Comment: Decibels are logarithmic values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel

Comment: Perhaps he needs the **logarithmic mean**?

Comment: There was a similar question on physics exchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46228/averaging-decibels

Comment: @schnauss perhaps you can get something useful from this link: https://www.cirrusresearch.co.uk/blog/2013/01/noise-data-averaging-how-do-i-average-noise-measurements/ . Not sure what kind of average you need, but noise data average sounds pretty close to what you need, to me. In any case, this doesn't really sound like a programming question, but rather about a logical one. Too much theory that is beyond programming is involved here, I would recommend you to come back with a formula so that we can work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on definition of Decibel (@schnauss)[Decibel on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel).
There are 2 definitions: power and amplitude decibels. I take a look on [power decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Power_quantities).

Get rid of logarithms, find average and reapply logarithm.

[image: mathematics behind the calculations]

```js
var samples = [40, 50, 55, 80, 45],
    x = 0.0;

samples.forEach(value => {
    x += Math.pow(10, value/10.0);
});

var average = x / samples.length,
    logAverage = 10 * Math.log10(average);
    
console.log(logAverage);
```

**Result is ~73 dB**

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach may be to invert the log in the values, do the mean as usual, and then applying the log to the result. It may be a more efficient way of doing this operation, but if performance is not critical, you could try it.

I can't try this code, so if anything goes wrong feel fry to say anything! Any suggestion is welcome.

EDIT: forgot to re-do the log at the end, just added it

```js
// These values are in decibels
const samples = [40, 50, 55, 80, 45];

//Undo the log. Be careful if base 10 is not the one you are using!
samples.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    array[index] = Math.pow(10, element);
});

document.getElementById('samples').innerText = JSON.stringify(samples);

let total = 0;
 
 samples.forEach(value => {
   total = total + value;
 });

const average = Math.log10(total / samples.length);

document.getElementById('avg').innerText = JSON.stringify(average);
```

```html
<div>
  Decibel samples:
  <span id="samples"></span>
</div>

<div>
  Average:
  <span id="avg"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is the appropriate formula. (Decibels can be quite confusing.)

```js
const mean = (ns) => ns.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / (ns.length || 1)

const decibelAverage = (decibels) =>
    10 * Math.log10(mean(decibels.map(n => 10 ** (n / 10))))

console.log(decibelAverage([40, 50, 55, 80, 45])) //~> 73.03013877157564
```

The point is that a decibel represents 10 times the base-10 logarithm of the power level.  (There is another decibel type as well.  If you need that there's a square root floating around somewhere.)